# Converting TensorflowJS's BodyPix model to TensorFlow Lite

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, tensorflow.js, coreml

I have come across googles new BodyPix TensorflowJS model today, and I want to get it running on Android and iOS, but using TensorFlow Lite and CoreML. I was wondering if someone could point me towards the best way to convert this model into TensorFlow Lite. I have done conversions between TensorFlow Lite and CoreML so that's no problem.

I've read a few documents on how to do this, but im a little confused as those documents mention a model.json file or something similar, which the BodyPix src directory contains a multitude of files, which im unsure on what any of them do.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/body-pix

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.